# How get more than one data from #authentication.getPrincipal(). in Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, syntax-error, thymeleaf

I get information about user and send it with AJAX to server.

this work fine:

```
<script>
       /*<![CDATA[*/  
            data.orderId = [[${theOrder.id}]]; 
            data.UserId = [[${#authentication.getPrincipal().getId()}]]; /*]]>*/
</script>
```

When I add One more:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/ data.fromUserName = [[${#authentication.getPrincipal().getName()}]]; /*]]>*/
```

it broke the code and throw error in browser console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.
I check .getName() on thymeleaf and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it don't work with one than one variable. But in Thymeleaf 3 this constration work with many varibles:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var username = [[${session.user.name}]];
</script>
```